# Excel2016: Generate ID based on multiple criteria (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

I am trying to generate Batch ID based on Course, Date, & Time. All the rows which have the same `Course+Date+Time` combination should have the same Batch ID. All subsequent combinations should have incremental IDs

```
Batch ID = LEFT(C2,3)&TEXT(<code formula>,"000")
```

No VBA, only Excel 2016 formula, please.

Sample data snapshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier and more readable to meet your requirement in three steps, rather than a single formula.

1. Create a unique ID based on the Course, Date and Time.

   **Formula:**

   =CONCATENATE(UPPER(LEFT($C3,3)),TEXT($D3,"ddmmyy"),TEXT($E3,"hhmm"))

   **Breakdown:**

   LEFT($C3,3) - take the first three characters of the Course

   UPPER() = make the first three characters of the Course uppercase

   TEXT($D3,"ddmmyy") = take the date, turn it into text and apply a format

   TEXT($E3,"hhmm") = take the time, turn it into text and apply a format
2. Create a lookup table of the unique ID and Batch ID

   Copy all the unique Ids that have been created in step 1

   Paste them into a new column separate to your data

   On the Data menu tab, select **Remove Duplicates** in the data tools

   Add the Batch ID to lookup.

   This way the Batch ID can be generate via formula if the Unique Id's are sorted using **Sort A to Z**.

   See the attached image.
3. Lookup the unique ID to get the Batch ID

   =VLOOKUP($F3,$I$3:$J$7,2,FALSE)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stretch but try in `F2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C$2:C2,C2,D$2:D2,D2,E$2:E2,E2)>1,LOOKUP(2,1/((C$1:C1=C2)*(D$1:D1=D2)*(E$1:E1=E2)),F$1:F1),UPPER(LEFT(C2,3))&TEXT(MAX(IFERROR((LEFT(F$1:F1,3)=LEFT(C2,3))*RIGHT(F$1:F1,3),0))+1,"000"))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! The formula works. Will it work for 100,000 rows without crashing? Could you please explain the part within the TEXT function, can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @ArnabMitra, that part stands for the `FALSE` parameter in the `IF` function where we test if any of the preceding values starts with the same three letters **and** multiply it by the last three characters. If this ends up being an error it will equal zero. Best to step through the formula using the build-in formula evaluation. Also, it should *not* crash but being an array formula a 100000 rows will weigh heavily on performance. Also, if this has answered your question feel free to accept as answer and click the "tick" to the left of the answer to mark as such.